# rails 3 - given XXX.created_at - How to output the 3 digit month + Day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Give a model.created_at

I've been able to use:

```
<%="#{time_ago_in_words(model.created_at)} ago "%>
```

What is the helper to output something like

- Oct 8
- Sep 23
- Aug 31
- Jul 11

Bonus points, if it outputs like above, but for any records that were created today (not 24hrs ago but today). it shows the time, example:

- 4:31pm
- 1:20pm
- 9:31am
- Oct 8
- Sep 23
- Aug 31
- Jul 11

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a helper method like:

```
def formated_date(date)
  if date > Time.now.beginning_of_day
    return date.strftime("%l:%M%p")
  end
  date.strftime("%b %d")  
end
```